# Colocar objetos sobre imagem

Tags: android, imagem, processamento-de-imagens, biblioteca

Gostaria de saber como poderia fazer para colocar objetos sobre uma imagem no Android. Um exemplo seria ter a foto e sobre ela colocar outras imagens como círculos, triângulos etc...

Como poderia fazer isso no android?

Comment: Olá Hiago. A sua pergunta está bastante ampla. Eu sugiro que você a edite para focar em um problema específico que tenha (por exemplo, como desenhar algo sobre uma imagem). Tirar foto, criar editor, salvar imagem, são outros problemas (para os quais você pode abrir outras perguntas). Mesmo assim, seria bacana você também compartilhar o que você já tentou fazer. E, aliás, solicitar bibliotecas não é bem o foco deste site (que não é um fórum, vale lembrar). Para esse tipo de solicitação, você sempre pode utilizar o [chat].

Comment: Olá HiagoSouza, concordo com o @LuizVieira, é muito ampla, mas acredito que o maior problema neste caso é o editor da imagem, tenta dar uma olhada nesta [biblioteca](https://github.com/yaa110/Effects-Pro) outra opção também seria o  [aviary](https://developers.aviary.com/)

Comment: Já experimentou usar canvas?

Comment: verdade, esqueci o foco do site. não sabia onde recorrer por isso procurei o SOP

Comment: Sem problemas Hiago: ainda dá pra corrigir! É só [edit] a pergunta para torná-la mais objetiva!

Comment: @LuizVieira tentei deixar mais objetiva. Obrigado a dica.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema com a resposta? Ou precisa de mais alguma informação?

Comment: Me desculpe já dei os pontos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A boa maneira pode ser talvez usando o `Canvas`:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.foobar);
d.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
d.draw(canvas);
```

#### Detalhes

- [Canvas e Drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)

Comment: No caso, `R.drawable.foobar` é o *resource* da imagem? Apesar da amplitude da pergunta (do jeito que ela está no momento), acho a sua resposta boa e você já leva o meu +1. Mas acho que precisava dar uma leve melhorada no exemplo para facilitar o entendimento de uma audiência maior e *focar no desenho sobre uma imagem*.

Comment: @seamusd, obrigado pela resposta. assim que implementar eu dou um feedback. funcionando eu ofereço novamente os 100 pontos e darei eles a você.